# iPhoneX Support in Unity3D 4.7.2 Basic

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, iphone-x

I made launchScreen.storyboard and added exact unity3d splash. But game crashes with below console log.

```
You are using Unity iPhone Basic. You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen from your game
```

Now getting unity splash screen, displayed properly in iPhone. But its crashing. If I use assets catalog then it works perfect..but no iPhoneX support. I want to support iPhoneX in unity3D 4.7.2

Here is my LaunchScreen.storyboard : https://app.box.com/s/i9k8ryfatvqaid8f8z6kgq1v41il2rof

[image]
How to Fix ?

**UPDATE:** Now with Xcode 9.2, you can easily add iPhoneX launch screen in assets catalog. This is very easy fix...Cheers!

Comment: Unity cannot find the splash screen. This looks like the problem. Like  I said in your other question, I do think you will into many other problems while using very old Unity version to do build for new iOS and Android devices. Maybe using the Pro version might solve your problem since it will remove the splash screen restriction imposed on the free version

Comment: @Programmer thanks for your suggestions, I know Unity Pro fix problem..but I want it in basic version.  In Unity 4.7.2 ipv6 server connectivity problem fixed. Its mentioned in unity release notes. So no other problem with 4.7.2 except iPhoneX support. Hope to find solution.